# How are the gamertags that appear in Killzone 3's multiplayer cutscene determined?

Tags: killzone-3

In *Killzone 3*, when a match of Operations ends, a cutscene follows where some of the players on the losing team are being custodied by some of the players on the winning team. What determines which players get to be in said cutscene?

Comment: I always thought it was random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always thought that it was the top 3 players of each team.

[Those](http://community.killzone.com/t5/Killzone-3-PS3/Pickyness-on-Operation-Cutscenes/td-p/898497) [links](http://community.killzone.com/t5/Killzone-3-PS3/How-often-are-you-in-the-Ops-Cutscenes/m-p/1108117) seems to tell that sometimes one or two guys are selected randomly.

Comment: Thanks I always thought it wasn't fully random. Top 3 seems about right.

Comment: In some cutscene, we can see more than 3 persons, so at that moment, I guess we see the top 3 and the other are random.